# Que veut dire « alléguer » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Que veut dire « alléguer » ? Allant sur le Wiktionnaire pour trouver une réponse, celui-ci me donne les explications suivantes :

> 1. Citer comme autorité, comme preuve de ce qu’on affirme, comme justification
> 2. Citer l'auteur d'une information, d'une nouvelle, etc.
> 3. Mettre en avant.

Pour plus de certitude, j’ai aussi recouru à un dictionnaire pour traduire ce mot en néerlandais, mais il me rend seulement quelques tournures qui veulent dire « mettre en avant ». Alors, je me suis penché sur les deux premières lignes.

La première ligne contient des mots qui ne se laissent pas traduire univoquement.
Si je clique sur un de ces mots, une nouvelle page apparaît,  c’est pourquoi j’ai mal à comprendre cette ligne. Voici une tentative de l’exprimer autrement :

> Montrer que quelque chose est vrai en disant qu’il y a un savant qui y souscrit.
>   Établir un fait en faisant recours à une personne bien vue qui a dit le même fait autrefois.

Le Wiktionnaire ne fournit pas d’exemples de l’emploi de ce mot, donc je ne sais pas comment il s'utilise. Allègue-t-on un énoncé, ou est-ce la personne que l’on allègue ? Et quels mots faut-il utiliser pour conjoindre ces choses ?

Comment: On allègue un fait/une idée, pas une personne. Est-ce que la [définition du TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/all%C3%A9guer) est plus claire pour toi ?

Comment: Oui, c'est un bon soutien. Merci pour partager ce lien avec moi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alléguer un fait ou une idée, c'est affirmer qu'il est vrai, en se basant sur l'autorité d'une personne.

Le mot est souvent employé de manière négative, pour critiquer ce qu'affirme quelqu'un comme relevant d'un argument d'autorité

« Vous alléguez que le conducteur était ivre, mais nous n'avons pas encore reçu les résultats du test d'alcoolémie ! »
« Vos allégations sont mensongères ! »

Dans le domaine scientifique, ce terme peut être utilisé pour montrer qu'une chose est considérée vraie sur la base de l'autorité seule.

« On peut alléguer, en suivant le raisonnement du prof. Schmurtz, que X est Y ».

Comment: Merci pour vôtre réponse, vous avez rendu ce mot encore un peu plus clair. Vôtre explication fait un bon apport à ce que j’ai compris du Trésor de la Langue Française. Néanmoins, il y a encore quelques choses de vôtre propos que je ne comprends pas. D’ailleurs, « on peux », c’est bien épellé?

Parlant du champ scientifique, le mot a également un sous-entendu défavorable ? Autrement dit, est-ce que ce mot y exprime qu’on suit aveuglement quelqu’un qui est bien vu ? Où emploie-t-on le mot pareillement s’il agit d’un propos avéré autrefois, c’est-à-dire qu’on a relu cet énoncé murement ?

Comment: merci, c'est bien entendu "on peut".

Comment: pour revenir à la question, dans le contexte scientifique, le sens n'est pas forcément défavorable, mais exprime à mon avis une prise de distance : on accepte (temporairement) une hypothèse, pour simplifier un problème annexe, ou pour la démontrer ou l'infirmer par la suite.